# How to deploy java application on pivotal cloud?

Tags: java, javafx, cloud, cloud-foundry

I have jar file "MyApplication.jar" while deploying it on "Pivotal cloud foundry" by using command

---

cf push MyApplication -d path/MyApplication.jar
Following Exception has occured
"ERR Error: Could not find or load main class MyApplication.MyApp"

Comment: Debug by making `java -jar MyApplication.jar` work.

Comment: java -jar MyApplication.jar is woking fine but only problem while deploying it on pivotal cloud.

Comment: What JRE is installed on the machine that fails to run the JAR? It's possible it doesn't have JavaFX.

Comment: jre 8 is installed on my machine and its a JavaFX application jar file.

Comment: But your machine can run the JAR, can't it? You need to know what JRE is installed on the "pivotal cloud foundry" server.

Comment: Can anyone tell me the procedure to deploy jar on Pivotal cloud foundry?

Comment: How to get JRE information of  "pivotal cloud foundry" server?

Comment: Um, are you sure you copied the command correctly? That should be `-p`, not `-d`.

Comment: Sorry it's my mistake.it's -p only.

Comment: What should be in api.my-cloudfoundry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason seems to wrong parameter in push command . **-d** is for domain not for application.
There could be two possible solutions :

**Solution 1:** Try with correct command :
from CLI (Cloud fondry commandline)cd to dir where jar resides.
Then : cf push MyApplication -f ManifestFilename
(-f is required of your manifest file resides other that corrent folder of have diffent name than manifest.yml)

**Solution 2:** With above command push an executable jar. Prepare your jar as executable jar.
java -jar myJARFile.jar